The efficiency of Java loop execution method? The different optimizations for the code
JDK: 21
look this code.
public static void createDirect(long num) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("张三");
        user.getName();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("createDirect:" + (end - start));
}

loop 100000000 times time consuming：34
When I move code User user = new User(); out of loop. Like this
public static void createDirect(long num) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    User user = new User();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        user.setName("张三");
        user.getName();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("createDirect:" + (end - start));
}

loop 100000000 times time consuming：80
The time consuming increases, why?
There is no need to create objects in the loop. Shouldn't the time consumption be reduced?
I want to know whether the compiler has different optimizations for the above code, rather than how to conduct performance testing.

Well, if you want to know the answere - do look at bytecode and you get it.

Learn about benchmarking and maybe take a look at https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

@OlegCherednik: I would be very wary of drawing conclusions from the bytecode. Often the JIT compiler (which is harder to keep track of, given multi-pass optimizations) is much more relevant.

Look up "dead code elimination".

There is no need to set the same name in the same object 100000000 times, either.

is there really "dead code" (as detectable by compiler or virtual machine) in posted code?

Is not the same question as How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java? . please reopen it.

This question has been marked as a duplicate because it uses a method of measuring the performance of code that will produce lies.

This is definitely not a duplicate of How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?. Regardless of whether this a suitable question or not it has been closed for bogus reasons. This is a question about a particular performance results. Tips about how to create a benchmark are good as comments but not a valid reason for closing the question.

@王成委: I guess that your performance results are because of this: In the first example the JIT compiler realizes during runtime that user is never used outside the loop. It inlines setName and getName and realizes that they only affects the fields of user which is never used. So JIT eliminates the object creation and the method calls. Then JIT sees that the loop is now empty to it eliminates the loop altogether.

The second example is a little harder for JIT because user keeps existing outside the loop. But I guest in the end the result is the same, but it takes a little longer for JIT to get there.

@王成委: You could experiment by messing around with the code in various ways. For example: Call the same version of createDirect twice in a single program run. Compare the timings for the first run of createDirect to the second run. You can also pass arguments to java to make it print the JIT compilation log.
